# Mean Average Precision for Multi-Label Multi-Class Data

Tags: matlab, performance, metric

I am trying to write a code for computing the Mean Average Precision ([MAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Mean_average_precision)) for multi-label data. To give a more intuitive understanding kindly please look below

[image]

I have written the code for the MAP computation in MATLAB but it is quite slow. Essentially it is **slow** due to the computation of the variable **Lrx** for each value of **r**.

**I wanted to make my code much faster.**

```
function [map] = map_at_R(sim_x,L_tr,L_te)

%sim_x(i,j) denote the sim bewteen query j and database i
tn = size(sim_x,2);
APx = zeros(tn,1);
R = 100;

for i = 1 : tn    
    Px = zeros(R,1);
    deltax = zeros(R,1);
    label = L_te(i,:);
    [~,inxx] = sort(sim_x(:,i),'descend');

    % compute Lx - the denominator in the map calculation
    % Lx = 1 if the retrieved item has the same label with the query or
    % shares atleast one label else Lx = 0
    search_set = L_tr(inxx(1:R),:);

    for r = 1 : R        
        %% FAST COMPUTATION
        Lrx = sum(diag(repmat(label,r,1)*search_set(1:r,:).')>0);

        %% SLOW COMPUTATION
%         Lrx = 0;
%         for j=1:r
%             if sum(label*(search_set(j,:)).')>0
%                 Lrx = Lrx+1;
%             end
%         end        

        if sum(label*(search_set(r,:)).')>0
            deltax(r) = 1;
        end

        Px(r) = Lrx/r;
    end
    Lx = sum(deltax);
    if Lx ~=0
        APx(i) = sum(Px.*deltax)/Lx;
    end
end
map = mean(APx);
```

The input to the code is this :

```
% sim_x = similarity score matrix or distance matrix
sim_x = gallery_data_size X probe_data_size 

% L_tr = labels of the gallery set
L_tr = gallery_data_size X c

% L_te = labels of the probe set
L_te = probe_data_size X c

% where c is the number of classes
% please note that the data is multi-label
```

Is it possible to make the code even faster? I am unable to figure it out myself.

Comment: can you vectorize the other loops too? you might be able to trade memory for speed.

Comment: @felixthecat I would need your help for that. There are essentially two loops. I do not know how to vectorize the outer loop. Even vectorizing the inner loop should help. Can you help me on that ?

Comment: sorry @roni, I do not have time to write this code. I would need to try it out myself with some data. But another thing, that you might want to look into: the labels are boolean vectors, right? if this is so, maybe you can also gain some speed by replacing `sum()` and other arithmetic operations by locical operations `and()`, `or()` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the delta function `APx(i) = sum(Px.*deltax)/Lx` you are throwing away some proportion of your `r = 1:R` iterations. Since the delta can be defined before the loop, why not only iterate through `r` where `deltax(r) == 1`.

```
% r_range is equivalent to find(deltax(r) == 1);
%Edit 1/4 %Previously :: r_range = find(sum(label*(search_set(1:R,:)).')>0);
% Multiply each row by label
mult = bsxfun(@times,(search_set(1:R,:)),label);
% Sum each row 
r_range = find(sum(mult,2)>0);
% r_range @ i should equal find(deltax) @ i

Px = zeros(numel(r_range,1);

for r = r_range
    Lrx = sum(diag(repmat(label,r,1)*search_set(1:r,:).')>0);
    Px(r == r_range) = Lrx/r;
end 

Lx = numel(r_range);
if Lx ~=0
    APx(i) = sum(Px)/Lx;
end
```

Comment: Hi I checked your code but the results are not matching. Maybe there is a bug ?

Comment: `r_range` needs to be the same as `find(deltax)` in the original code (when you check, make sure `i` is consistent). If they are not the same, you need to adjust `r_range = ...` so that `sum` and `label*` collapse across the second dimension of `search_set`